# New System Windows 8.1 dual boot and virtualbox

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, virtualbox

I just bought a new windows 8 machine to run Linux on.  I also want to create a dual boot and a virtual drive in virtualbox with the same windows.

The first thing I did was to create the windows backup on a thumb drive, then I switched HDDs to a smaller one for running the system.  When it finishes reinstalling, I want to create a dual boot for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and then a virtual drive for VirtualBox.

The dual boot will probably not be a problem, but I am not sure how to install windows on the virtual drive or if I'll have problems since it is the OEM version that came with my hardware.

Has anyone successfully installed Windows 8.1 into a VirtualBox?
Is there anything I need to know?

My original 1 TB HDD that came with the system is removed for protection with the original windows in it.  I have several drives to set up without fear of losing data.

Comment: You will be better off asking on the Virtual Box forums as it does not appear this question is directly about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Windows 8.1 from the recovery thumb-drive.
It installed:
                                   (Flags)
ntfs     RECOVERY            600 MiB  hidden, diag 
unknown                      128 MiB  msftres
ntfs     Acer                120 GiB  msftdata
ntfs     Push Button Reset 14.89 GiB  hidden, diag

Ubuntu reduced the Acer partition and created three partitions:

fat32   /target/boot/efi ESP 300 MiB boot
ext4    /target               83 GiB 
linux-swap                  3.82 GiB

Tested the boot: 
First time, I got a micro-text of grub.
I chose Windows and aborted by turning off the computer (I wasn't ready to register.)
When it came up, I did not get the grub.  It went to booting Windows.

Then I rebooted and chose the bios boot options, which gave me a choice of Windows (at top) or Ubuntu.  When I chose Ubuntu, it came up fine.
Did a shutdown and powered the computer back on.  The computer came back up on Windows.

The end result is that with UEFI, dual boot appears to be managed by the bios. When I choose Ubuntu, it gives grub.  When I choose Windows it brings up windows.

And when I turn on the computer and leave the bios to work, it chooses Windows.
(I'll check the bios to see if the order can be changed.)

This is different, not what I expected, but not bad either.

As for the virtualbox issue, I'm off to look for the proper forum.

Thank you

PS I hoped I could close this, so moderator, you may close this issue.

Comment: the behavior - select which OS to boot in your bios - is normal and often confusing to users who are not familiar with their bios or these options.

Comment: I just realized I answered my own question, LOL.